# jquery UI Draggable Sortable Looking for the Id of the dropped object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

The big picture is I am looking to post all the elements dragged from one list and dropped into the sortable ul list.  I want to be able to pull an element more than once and I want the list to be sortable and have the order come through in the form submission.  If there is an easier way to do this I am totally open.

I am to the point where I am attempting to get the id of (or even better assign an id to) the dragged item and append an href to that item to remove it from the list if needed.  However both the $(this) and the event.target are both targeting the sortable ul container rather than the li that was just dropped into it.

Once I can actually target that specific item I was going to throw open and close form tags inside the sortable ul and append hidden input fields to the lis as they are dragged across.

Question 1: How do I interact with the dropped li?
Question 2: Is there an easier way to do this?

HTML:

```
<ul id="draggable_list">
    <li id="1" class="draggable ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li id="2" class="draggable ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li id="3" class="draggable ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li id="4" class="draggable ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li id="5" class="draggable ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">

</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if(!ui.item.data('tag') && !ui.item.data('handle')) {
                ui.item.data('tag', true);
            }
        },
        receive: function (event, ui) {   
            $(this).append('<a href="" class="dragRemove">x</a>');
            alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
        }
}).droppable({ });
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#sortable',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });

    $("ul, li").disableSelection();    

    </script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to the `ui.item` instead of `e.target` to get the id of the dropped item, however looks like you want to access to ***the cloned*** item, but jQuery does not provide any event so that we can listen to and access the cloned item via the event info argument. So we need to use a workaround here like in this code:

```
var currentChildren;
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if(!ui.item.data('tag') && !ui.item.data('handle')) {
            ui.item.data('tag', true);
        }
    },
    activate: function(event, ui){
       currentChildren = $(this).children();
    },    
    receive: function (event, ui) {          
        $(this).children().not(currentChildren)
               .append('<a href="" class="dragRemove">x</a>');            
    }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/G5ek4/3/).

Comment: The id that it is giving in your demo is actually that of the item in the droppable list.  The newly created item that is in the sortable list doesn't seem to have an id and I still can't seem to add an id, or append the remove a href to it.

Comment: @jessier3 what is the exact *newly created item* you mean here? the `a` element? it's obviously that you did not add code to add any `id` for that element, also the `id` should be unique, so you should have a mechanism to generate the ids so that they are unique, anyway it's unclear on what you want. The dropped item can be accessed via `ui.item`, that's a solution to the asked problem, but looks like you have some other problem which is unclear here.

Comment: The problem I am having is that when I do $(ui.item).append('<a href="" class="dragRemove">x</a>'); it is not appending to the dropped item, it is appending to the original item.  The stated problem is that I am trying to manipulate the dropped item, not the original one.

Comment: @jessier3 the feature of automatic appending the clone of the dropped item to the connected list is convenient but it has a problem such as in this case. Looks like it does not have any event to listen to (such as `itemAppended`, ...), so we have to use a workaround by handling the `activate` event, save the current `children`, and in the `receive` event handler, we just need to exclude all the current children to get the appended item. Please check the updated code as well as the updated demo.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to use `.droppable()` method, when using `connectToSortable` option, the sortable list will be able to receive some draggable item (having `connectToSortable` option set appropriately).